# Windows 2008R2 SNMP service not binding to all IP addresses

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, snmp

I'm having trouble with the Microsoft SNMP agent on Windows 2008R2 not listening on all IP addresses on a number of servers.

When I do `netstat -ano` I can see that it's apparently listening on all IP's:

```
UDP    0.0.0.0:161            *:*                                    996
```

However in practice it only seems to be listening on one IP address on each server. What I can't work out is the selection criteria.

I'd actually far rather it just listen on one IP address, but one of my choosing.

Is there a way to force the MS SNMP Agent service to listen on a specific IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the SNMP service is in fact listening on all interfaces, but your ability to use it on all interfaces is blocked by the Windows firewall. Run wf.msc and take a look at the inbound rules for SNMP - the installation of the SNMP feature would normally have created one rule for the domain profile and one for the public profile. [Check the "Scope" tab for restrictions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753558.aspx) on certain local IP addresses.

Comment: heh...close. Turns out there's something wacky in my nagios unix box's IPTables config. Outbound connections to the SNMP agents from a bunch of other machines (snmpget) are fine. But for some reason this box is being selective about which IP address it'll allow an outbound snmp connection to, even though there is no rule denying access to my windows boxes.